# Add a drill down and add a time stamp

Tags: excel, vba

I have this spreadsheet to reconcile data. So once I received final data, I reconciled it to an internal system vs external system.

What I am trying to add to the spreadsheet is two columns to record once
data is "Final" or "Under Reviewed":

Column AC: I have a Drill Down with "Final" or "Under Reviewed"
Column AD: is where I want to add the Time Stamp

I have the following Excel VBA code, but it stamps the time stamp on same cell as the drill down once Final is selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim fn As Integer
Dim ts As Integer

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AC7:AC42")) Is Nothing Then

fn = [AC7:AC42].Find(Target.Value).Column


If Cells(Target.Row, fn) = "Final" Then
Cells(Target.Row, fn).Value = Now
Cells(Target.Row, fn).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM"
Cells(Target.Row, fn).Locked = False
End If
End If
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
End Sub
```

So this code right now adds the TIMESTAMP if I select "Final" from the Drill Down list in the same column cell.

I want the drill down selection in Column AC and the Time Stamp on Column AD.

I know I am missing a step or a block of code but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim ts As Integer

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AC7:AC42")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Final" Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect
            With Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, "AD") 
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM"     
                .Value = Now
                .Locked = False
            End with
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect '<<<Protect?
        End If  'is Final
    End If      'is in AC

End Sub
```